# Combobox filled with Enum

Tags: c#

How can I bind a specific `Enum` in a `Combobox` ?

```
public enum EduTypePublicEnum
  {
    [RMSEnumItem("1", "Properties.Resources.SEduAlumn")]
    Alumn,
    [RMSEnumItem("2", "Properties.Resources.SEduProfesor")]
    Profesor,
    [RMSEnumItem("3", "Properties.Resources.SEduAll")]
    All
  }

  public class EduTypePublic : RMSEnum<EduTypePublicEnum> { };
```

In my Form

```
public EduAvisosForm()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     this.myComboBox.DataSource = Edu.Consts.EduTypePublic.Enums;
     this.myComboBox.DisplayMember = "Alumn";
     this.myComboBox.ValueMember = "Alumn";
}
```

But, with or without the `ValueMember` occurs an error. When I put this code without the `ValueMember` occurs an error asking for the `ValueMember` when I put it, doesn't work.

`"Is not possible define SelectedValue in a ListControl with empty ValueMember"`

```
public abstract class RMSEnum<TEnumType>
    {
        protected RMSEnum();

        public static string CodeList { get; }
        public static string[] Codes { get; }
        public static string DescriptionList { get; }
        public static string[] Descriptions { get; }
        public static object[] Enums { get; }

        public static string Code(TEnumType value);
        public static string Description(string code);
        public static string Description(TEnumType value);
        public static TEnumType Enum(string code);
    }
```

Comment: What is `Edu.Consts.EduTypePublic.Enums`?

Comment: Return an object array with [alumn, profesor, all]

Comment: I am concerned with this line `this.myComboBox.DataSource = Edu.Consts.EduTypePublic.Enums`

Comment: Enums return an object array, and in my case is [Alumn, Profesor, All].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data source items should have properties which you specified as display and value members. E.g. dictionary KeyValuePairs have properties named Key and Value:

```
 this.myComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
 this.myComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
 this.myComboBox.DataSource = 
      Enum.GetValues(typeof(EduTypePublicEnum))
          .Cast<EduTypePublicEnum>()
          .Select(e => new { 
               Key = e.ToString(), // possibly read localized string
               Value = e
           }).ToList();
```

Comment: "First - you should set display and value member before you assign data source" - This is not true. I've set `DataSource` first all the time

Comment: @T.S. let me check, maybe I forgot something

Comment: @T.S. Actually, you should.  If you set the DataSource before setting the other members, that will unnecessarily make extra "refresh" calls to the control.  With the DataSource null, nothing happens when you set the Member properties.

Comment: @LarsTech I remembered that something was about setting members first!

Comment: I read it here a long time ago: [12 Tips To Speed-up Your Windows Forms Applications](http://devcomponents.com/blog/?p=361).  Item #8.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Ok, good to know this optimization. Spasibo